# How to edit database info and retain values in forms after submit PHP mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am creating a profile page with forms that displays the user's account information from the database in a form. I am using php for this. Would greatly appreciate your help!

Name:
Email:

How can i edit the values in the forms and retain the edited values in the forms after submission?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="name">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="type" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" class="form-control" placeholder=""><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" class="form-control" placeholder=""><br>
    </div>
</div>


<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE UserID ='1'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) ;
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);    
    $name = $row ['Name'];
    $userid = $row ['Email'];
?>           

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$n1 = $_POST['name'];
$n2 = $_POST['email'];
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE userprofile SET Name ='$n1' WHERE UserID ='1'");
mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE userprofile SET Email ='$n2' WHERE UserID = '1'");
}
```

how can i edit them and retain the edited values inside after submitting? Thank you. I tried this filter/trim method but it only retains the value before the submission.

Comment: Using the existing code, after updating the userprofile table fetch the information one more time and display it. Or place the update code before the code you have for fetching the record.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve, and what is your problem.

Let's assume you are displaying data describing user (in form), that are fetched from the database. 
In this case, after submitting you have to run script that will update data in your database. After updating, your code should redirect user BACK to page he were visiting before, so fetching user data from database will be done again and data presented in your form will be always fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but it has a small bug. The email field is not displaying correctly. You need to replace this line:

$userid = $row ['Email'];

with

$email = $row ['Email'];